# .Net Compact Framework for Windows Embedded

Tags: compact-framework, windows-embedded-compact

Can I use .Net Framework(Regular) on windows 7 Compact Embedded  or I have to use .net compact framework only?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Embedded Compact, you must use the Compact Framework (for Windows Embedded Standard, however, you do use the full framework).  Full framework assemblies cannot be loaded and the full framework CLR will not execute under CE (Compact).